# can not retrive value from xpath for symbol but when it is int then it work correctly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver (JAVA)test web application.i would like test the weather the utilities are available on that country or not for availability/unavailability used symbol cross and tick. i was tried  all the combinations of xpath but it print blank value below is related html 
:

```
<li>
  <span ng-reflect-class-name="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>      
  <img alt="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-reflect-src="app/shared/images/surro_icon1.png" src="app/shared/images/surro_icon1.png" ng-reflect-title="SAFE WATER: Not Available" title="SAFE WATER: Not Available">          
</li>
```

and related code for that :Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

```
WebElement SafeWater = driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[1]/app-utility-bar/div/ul/li[3]/span");
builder.moveToElement(SafeWater).perform();
String availabilitySafeWater = SafeWater.getText();
System.out.println( "safe water :" + availabilitySafeWater);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<span>` tag doesn't have text, that is why you get blank values. I think you are looking for the title of the `<img>` tag

```
WebElement safeWater = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[1]/app-utility-bar/div/ul/li[3]/img"));
builder.moveToElement(safeWater).perform();
String availabilitySafeWater = safeWater.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println( "safe water :" + availabilitySafeWater);
```

Result: `safe water : SAFE WATER: Not Available`

As a side note, try not to use absolute path. For example, if `glyphicon` is unique class name you can do

```
WebElement safeWater = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@class='glyphicon']"));
```

Or even using `By.className`

```
WebElement safeWater = driver.findElement(By.className("glyphicon"));
```